# C: Pause page when full

Tags: mysql, window

i'm making a client database in C, and I couldn't find a way to when it lists all the people, when the console or the window is full, it pauses the printing to the screen and displays a message like "Press a key to display another page", in a way like vi can show the next page using a single press... If anyone knows how to get a quick around at this...

Comment: Redirect it to `more` in the command line.

Comment: yes redirect it to more or less like **$ yourprg | less**

Comment: The question is so vague, it is not even clear if that is a programming problem.

Comment: This is usually a job for [the `curses` library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) or something like it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try to figure out how many rows your console has (On Linux: get the `$ROWS` variable from the environment). Then, before you print anything try to clear the console. You could use a call to `system("cls"); //Windows`  or`system("clear") //Linux` or use the ASCII character `printf("\033[2J");`. This makes sure that you will start in the first row.
Now you can simply use a loop like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < TOTAL_ELEMENTS; x++)
{
    if(x < COLS)
    {
        puts(rows[x]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Press [ENTER] to show the next line")
        getchar();
        printf("\033[F\r"); // Go to beginning of previous line to override (Not that portable)
        puts(rows[x]);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you can use a pager like `more` (Windows/Linux) or `most`/`less` (Linux) like @Eugene suggested in its comment

Comment: The size of your terminal can and will change. This is not enough.

Comment: If I recall correctly, then the $COLS variable will update whenever the size changes. And if not there would be ncurses as alternative...

Comment: Yeah, but you need to listen to the signal and update accordingly. This is deceptively difficult which is why `curses` exists. Throwing ANSI codes at `printf` only gets you so far.

Comment: Yes ncurses seams to be the best (and most portable) way

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what i was looking for.